# Getting error while compare with constant value (+10 or -10) with same currency using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have requirement like I need to compare one threshold value with sum of the total value (count) and will compare like based on threshold if threshold value +10 or -10 and selected records have same currency. Need to do the successful validation. If beyond more than +10 or -10 not allowed to success validation.

Script is failing if differnece is in negetive values(-) and its giving validation alert if its differnce is at positive values(-). Please sugges me the solution

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var theresholdVal = "10";
     $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
        var creditAmount = 0;
        $("#firstTable input:checked").each(function() {
            //get td(amount column value)
            var values = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1)").text()
            if (values != "") {
                creditAmount += parseFloat(values);
            }
        });
        $("#secondTable input:checked").each(function() {
            //get td(amount column value)
            var values = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1)").text()
            if (values != "") {
                creditAmount += parseFloat(values);
            }
        });
        $("#idCheckBoxLabel").text(creditAmount);
    })
    $("#idMatch").click(function() {
        var countVal = $("#idCheckBoxLabel").text();
        var jsonData1 = [];
        var jsonData2 = [];
        var $headers = $("#firstTable").find("th:not(:first)");
        var $rows = $("#firstTable").find("tbody tr input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(index) {
            const $cells = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:not(:first)");
            jsonData1[index] = {};
            $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
                jsonData1[index][$($headers[cellIndex]).text()] = $(this).text();
            });
        });
        var $headers = $("#secondTable").find("th:not(:first)");
        var $rows = $("#secondTable").find("tbody tr input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(index) {
            const $cells = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:not(:first)");
            jsonData2[index] = {};
            $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
                jsonData2[index][$($headers[cellIndex]).text()] = $(this).text();
            });
        });
        console.clear()
        //loop through json arrays
        for (let i = 0; i < jsonData1.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < jsonData2.length; j++) {
                console.log(jsonData1[i]['Currency'] + "--" + jsonData2[j]['Currency'])
                //check currency keys..
                if (jsonData1[i]['Currency'] !== jsonData2[j]['Currency']) {
                    alert("Currency is mismatched, please select same currency!!!");
                      return false;
                } else if (parseFloat(theresholdVal) <=
            countVal + parseFloat(theresholdVal) &&
          parseFloat(theresholdVal) <=
            countVal - parseFloat(theresholdVal)) {
                    alert("Selected value is more thereshold value");
                    return false;
                }else{
                 alert("Data matched successfully!!!");
                }
            }
        }
        $("#firstTable tbody input:checked").each(function() {
            if ($("#secondTable tbody tr td input").is(":checked")) {
                $("#secondTable").find("tbody tr input[type=checkbox]:checked").prop({
                    disabled: true,
                });
                $(this).prop({
                    disabled: true
                });
                $(this).closest("tr").css("background-color", "grey !important;");
            }
        });
    });
   
});
```

```css
td{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="idMatch">Match</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>Count::<span id="idCheckBoxLabel"></span>
<div>
      <div>
        <table datatable id="firstTable" [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="row-border hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
              <th>Amount</th>
              <th>Currency</th>
              <th>Nation</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>-40</td>
              <td>USD</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>-30</td>
              <td>USD</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>-85</td>
              <td>USD</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>67</td>
              <td>IND</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>IND</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>  <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>20</td>
              <td>IND</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>    <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>55</td>
              <td>IND</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>55</td>
              <td>IND</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>  <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>55</td>
              <td>IND</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>  <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>55</td>
              <td>IND</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>-100</td>
              <td>USD</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>89</td>
              <td>EUR</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <table datatable id="secondTable" [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="row-border hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
              <th>Amount</th>
              <th>Currency</th>
              <th>Nation</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>111</td>
              <td>EUR</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>22</td>
              <td>USD</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>90</td>
              <td>DNR</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>22</td>
              <td>USD</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>55</td>
              <td>IND</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>-30</td>
              <td>IND</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>-20</td>
              <td>IND</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>-10</td>
              <td>IND</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>IND</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>-40</td>
              <td>IND</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>-45</td>
              <td>IND</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think it's working?

Comment: Negetive difference values...it's not giving alert message, positive difference it is working fine.